# Custom Query num_rows returns wrong amount

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query, wpdb

So I have a custom query that fetches all posts in a given category. I am trying to get the number of rows returned but it is giving me the wrong number.

Instead of 11, I am getting 14. Does anyone know why?

```
<?php
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN userContests ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = userContests.contestID)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW() 
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN(3)
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
    "), OBJECT);

/*   $rows = $wpdb->num_rows;  <------ Wrongly returns 14 */

/*   $rows = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("      <--------- Correctly returns 11
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts
        LEFT JOIN userContests ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = userContests.contestID)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW() 
        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN(3)
        ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC")); */
echo "Number of rows = " .$rows;
?>
```

My work around seems like a waste of resources. Is there something more efficient?

Comment: ***"I have a custom query that fetches all posts in a given category"*** - Why? The WordPress query class supports querying on categories already, so why the custom SQL statement?

Comment: because I'm joining it with my own tables to add some values.

Comment: You could still do a join using a filter on [`posts_join`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Keyword_Search_in_Plugin_Table).

Comment: lol if you're willing to translate my query into one that uses filters you are more than welcome. I for one don't understand how to use 'em. I'm not building a plugin, I'm hardcoding this into my page.

Comment: Does your first query actually return 14 results? Like, if you loop through the object (not relying on the num_rows for a result count)? I guess my question is, is it just that num_results is not being set correctly, or do those two queries actually return different numbers of results?

Comment: The two queries return different numbers of results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total count of all the published posts in a particular category you can try this.

```
$all_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'cat' => 3 ) );
echo $all_posts->post_count;
```

or

```
$all_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'category_name' => 'uncategorized' ) );
echo $all_posts->post_count;
```

Just make sure to replace the 'category_name' or 'cat' with desired category.

Comment: That's what my workaround does, just with a custom query. The thing is though that num_row is SUPPOSED to return the number of rows returned by the last query made but clearly this isn't happening. I'm just wondering if there was a more efficient way than making two queries.